# Why I'm still getting web3 0.20.0 API in javascript?

Tags: web3js

I followed https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/getting-started.html and downloaded web3.min.js to my http host. In my html I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./web3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./libs/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            console.log(Web3.givenProvider || web3.currentProvider);
            web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || web3.currentProvider);

            console.log('Version:', web3.version.api);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I visit the page and see version is `0.20.0`. Also from the API doc, if it were `1.0` then `web3.version` should be `1.0` and there should be no member called `.api`.

What am I doing wrong here that I'm getting `0.20.0`?

Chrome. Metamask 3.13.4. Downloaded `web3.min.js` from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ethereum/web3.js/1.0/dist/web3.min.js

**EDIT**

Also tried download `web3.min.js` from the `master` branch. Same result.

**EDIT**

Actually for the current `1.0` I'm getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <<` from the file as I look into browser's debug window.

Answer (score 1):

Found out what happened. The `web3.min.js` file downloaded from `1.0` branch was broken by a bad commit. See this [particular version of the file](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/6816ce526981257bc1c81942366b71be1de357fe/dist/web3.min.js). Apparently it was a merge commit and the author didn't merge the conflict.

I guess the `web3.min.js` downloaded from `master` branch is still `0.20.0`.

I then downloaded `1.0` from a [previous commit](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ethereum/web3.js/35ae85a5d30500f7df20c47594d529af872ac88a/dist/web3.min.js) and solved the issue. Now it reads `1.0.0-beta.27`.